# Particular solution for $D^2 y + 4D y + 4y =18 \cosh x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

Set 
$$y_p = K \cosh x~, \quad y_p' = K \sinh x~, \quad y_p''=K\cosh x$$
and substitute these functions into the original equation, then:
$$K\cosh x+4K\sinh x+4K\cosh x=18\cosh x$$
the coefficient of $\cosh x$ would be $5K=18$, the coefficient of $\sinh x$ is $4K=0$.

(the contradiction would come out ??)

How could I get the particular solution $Y_p$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $18\cosh(x)=9(e^x+e^{-x})$ contains two exponential terms. This means that you need free parameters for both $$y_p(x)=Ae^x+Be^{-x}.$$ The same functions can also be parametrized using 
$$
y_p(x)=C\cosh(x)+D\sinh(x).
$$
Note that using $A,B$ leads to independent equations, while using $C,D$ leads to a coupled $2\times 2$ linear system, so it is easier to solve the first form and then substitute $e^{\pm x}=\cosh(x)\pm\sinh(x)$.

Comment: Answer is $e^x + 9e^-x $

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Which is then equal to $10\cosh x - 8\sinh x$.